# Unsupported Firebase Functions services?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm attempting to deploy a minimal Firebase Function based on an authentication trigger. I've worked successfully before with https and database triggers but I'm getting an error while deploying an authentication trigger ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events), [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onCreate)).

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

exports.onCreateUser = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .auth.user()
  .onCreate((user: admin.auth.UserRecord, context: functions.EventContext) => {
    console.log(`Triggered On Create User: ${user.email}, ${user.uid}.`);
  });
```

I receive the following error:

> Ignoring trigger "onCreateUser" because the service "firebaseauth.googleapis.com" is not yet supported.

I've tried changing my engine node version from `10` to `8` or changing the region to `europe-west2` or `us-central1` but any variations on my configuration would throw this error.

The documentation I've referenced does not mention a limited support for these triggers. Is there any page with an overview of unsupported services and their limitations?

Comment: Have you tried changing where you are hosting the function? Some locations can't handle firebase auth yet. Try moving it to London instead of Belgium and see if that helps.

Comment: As mentioned I removed the region parameter which should reset it back to it's default location. Is there any reference to which regions support which functions?

Comment: I don't see anything which explicitly states which locations support Firebase Auth, I just know that some have troubles with it, but here you can see which ones have better support for functions. https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/

Comment: When the Firebase CLI gives you error messages that aren't actionable, please contact Firebase support directly so they can collect information, investigate, and possibly escalate to engineering.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @A.S.H: I tried with `us-central1`, `europe-west1` and `europe-west2` without luck. Region doesn't appear to affect this behavior.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Doug Stevenson is probably right, there's not much else you can do. The only other thing I'd suggest is maybe try changing your `.onCreate((user: admin.auth.UserRecord, context : functions.EventContext))` to `.onCreate((user : any))` since you never use the `context` object, and also because that's the way it is stated in this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have mixed up my intent to run `serve` and `deploy` here. As I have been told by a very responsive support team the `serve` script spins up the [emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) and is currently limited to the following scopes:

- Functions
- Firestore
- Realtime Database
- Hosting

> For the development phase, however, you can make use of the interactive shell:
>
> $ firebase functions:shell
>
> ✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
>
> i  functions: Loaded functions: onCreateUser
>
> firebase > onCreateUser({"uid":"99999","email":"test@testing.com"})
>
> 'Successfully invoked function.'
>
> >  Triggered On Create User: test@testing.com, 99999.
>
> >  Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value